# How to do a search in a text file from a prepared list of country names, databases, then to replace these countries with id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables country and city

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

There is also a text document with countries and cities,

```
file.txt
country1;city1;num1;num2
country1;city2;num1;num2
country1;city3;num1;num2
country1;city4;num1;num2
country1;city5;num1;num2
country2;city1;num1;num2
country2;city2;num1;num2
country2;city3;num1;num2
country2;city4;num1;num2
country2;city5;num1;num2
country3;city1;num1;num2
country3;city2;num1;num2
country3;city3;num1;num2
country3;city4;num1;num2
country3;city5;num1;num2
country4;city1;num1;num2
country4;city2;num1;num2
country4;city3;num1;num2
country4;city4;num1;num2
country4;city5;num1;num2
country5;city1;num1;num2
country5;city2;num1;num2
country5;city3;num1;num2
country5;city4;num1;num2
country5;city5;num1;num2
country6;city1;num1;num2
country7;city1;num1;num2
```

my goal is to extract the countries and save them in the database so that they do not repeat, then get the id from the database and open a text file with countries and cities. Create a condition where from the database a search was made for country in a text document, found country and replaced with id, and then saved to the cities database along with “id”. How to do it?  I started, I managed to extract the id of the added countries to the database.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
 require_once 'db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<?php
$cities = array();
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$rows = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $sql = explode(";",htmlentities($buffer, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'));

        if (!in_array($sql[0], $cities)) {
             array_push($cities, $sql[0]);
             $rows = array_unique($cities);


        }
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++)
{
              try{
                $query = "INSERT INTO country
                  (name) 
                  VALUES (:name)";
                  $data = array(':name'=>$rows[$i]);
                  $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
                  $statement->execute($data);
              }
              catch(PDOException $e){
                  throw new Exception($e -> getMessage() . "  " . get_class($this).' -> '.__METHOD__);
                  $file = "exceptionlog.txt";
                  file_put_contents($file, $e -> getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
              } 
}
$position_id = $pdo->LastInsertId();
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM country");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($data as $values)
{
  echo $values[name]."<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is wrong with the code you have come up with so far? If it's not doing what you want it to, tell us what it is doing right and what it has left to do or what it is doing wrong in regards to how you want it to work and we can then help you to get it to do what you want it to.

Comment: see this line, getting the last identifier $ position_id = $ pdo-> LastInsertId ();
there is still a country in the database, how to replace the name of the country with id in a text file to get this view 
```
71;city1;num1;num2
71;city2;num1;num2
71;city3;num1;num2
71;city4;num1;num2
71;city5;num1;num2
72;city1;num1;num2 ....
``` and put it in the second table
Structure was added to the first database table.
77 - country7
76 - country6
75 - country5
74 - country4
73 - country3
72 - country2
71 - country1

Comment: How can you tell whether a city like 'London' refers to the one in Canada or England?